# Why is my computer generated code undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, string-length, password-generator

In JavaScript I am making a random password generator, where the user can choose the size (8 to 128 characters) and four parameters (if they want to include: numbers, capital and/or lowercase letters, and special characters).
I have made a large empty array where true responses to the parameters are then pushed into it, and following, the computer uses the large array to create a random password from the options.

```
// for loop

// sizeOfPassword = sizeOfPassword;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeOfPassword; i++) {
  var index = Math.floor.parseInt(Math.random() * allOptions.length);
  var computerChoice = allOptions[index];
  passwordElement.text = passwordString

  var passwordString = password.join("");
  var passwordElement = document.querySelector("password")
  randomPassword += computerChoice;

  var password = []
  // var = 0
  for (; i < sizeOfPassword - 1; i++) {
  password.push(randomCharacter)

  console.log(passwordString);
  console.log(passwordElement.text);
  passwordElement.text = passwordString
}
}

// Assignment Code
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = getPasswordInfo();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

Below is the second half of my code, but each time I test it in my browser, the computer's generated password returns as undefined.
How and where in my code can I properly assign the value of my computer generated string?

Comment: do you have the rest (htmp part) as well?

Comment: This is my HTML (as best as I can get it): @NinaScholz  '<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Password Generator</h1>
   </header>
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
    <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    <textarea
     readonly
     id="password"
     placeholder="Your Secure Password"
     aria-label="Generated Password"
    ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
    <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>'

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable.

Answer (score 0):

This `getPasswordInfo` is returning nothing.

```
var password = getPasswordInfo();
```

Try to `return passwordString` but difficult to tell, the code looks partial, the function `getPasswordInfo` is not defined in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include the code where 'getPasswordInfo' is defined. I'll try retuning 'passwordString' now. Thank you!